# How to initialize a TabPane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

In my GUI, I try to display a `TabPane` with other elements in it.

When calling the initialize-method of the specific scene, I can add the needed data to the first Tab.

How can I access the second one and add data there?`

Is there a method that gets called when u switch between the single tabs or is it possible to to it from the initialize method?

```
//all the fields

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    smsHandynumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().numberProperty());
    smsHandyproviderColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().providerProperty());
    displayHandyDetails(null);
    smsHandyList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> displayHandyDetails(newValue));

//  providernameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
//  provideramountColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().sizeProperty());
}

@FXML
private void displayHandyDetails(SmsHandy handy) {
    if (handy != null) {
        handyNumberLabel.setText(handy.getNumber());
        providerLabel.setText(handy.getProvider().getName());
        registerLabel.setText(handy.getDate().toString());
        receivedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(handy.getReceivedList().size()));
        sentLabel.setText(Integer.toString(handy.getSentList().size()));
        if (handy instanceof PrepaidSmsHandy) {
            balanceLabel.setText(Integer.toString(handy.getProvider().getCreditForSmsHandy(handy.getNumber()))
                    + " Cent on account");
            typeLabel.setText("Prepaid");
        } else {
            balanceLabel.setText(
                    Integer.toString(((TariffPlanSmsHandy) handy).getRemainingFreeSms()) + " free SMS left");
            typeLabel.setText("Tariff-Plan");
        }
    } else {
        handyNumberLabel.setText(" ");
        providerLabel.setText(" ");
        registerLabel.setText(" ");
        typeLabel.setText(" ");
        balanceLabel.setText(" ");
        receivedLabel.setText(" ");
        sentLabel.setText(" ");
    }
}

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    smsHandyList.setItems(mainApp.getHandyList());
}
```

}

So, this is the controller class. With the way it is, I can work obv. with the first tab pane (that is shown by default when u look at it).

FXML file: http://pastebin.com/MQ0C8EWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am not sure I understand the question properly.

If you are asking how to access GUI elements that are stored on the second `Tab` of your `TabPane`, the answer is:

`TabPane` is actually just a simple container, so if you insert two controls two the same `Tab` is (in terms of FXML injection) the same of you insert them to two separate `Tabs`.

I can see you have created a `TableView` in your FXML on the second tab like:

```
<TableView fx:id="providerList" layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="264.0" prefWidth="250.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
```

So, if you say:

```
@FXML TableView providerList;
```

in the class body of your controller, then in the `initialize` method of the controller you will have a reference to that `TableView` (absolutely the same as you have done with `smsHandyList` on the first `Tab`).

This is what is called "FXML injection". You can check this [post from Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) how to connect FXML with Java code.

Comment: First: yes, that is the question :) The thing is: I cant just access the Table on the second pane from the initialize method, i am getting a nullpoint exception there. I will copy it.

Comment: Yes, then please include the FXML injection part also

Comment: Or better to post your whole controller.

Comment: Nevermind. It took me a while but now it seems to work. There were just some syntax issues. I have redone the whole thing and it works fine now like you said, I can do it all from the initialize method. Thanks for helping me out anyway!

Comment: I am pretty new to stackoverflow so i dont have the reputition yet to give upvotes sorry^^

Answer (score 1):

First you initialize your tabpane, and then you initialize all the tabs you want. You can set the title and content, but don't forget to add all the tabs to your tabPane.

```
 TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
 Tab tab1 = new Tab();
 tab.setText("tab 1");
 tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.LIGHTSTEELBLUE));
 Tab tab2 = new Tab();
 tab.setText("tab 2");
 tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200, Color.RED));
 tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
```

more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html

Comment: I am using SceneBuilder with a JavaFx controller class. So i think its a bit different for me? I dont work with the tabs manually, so i cant just simply call another tab

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have much experience with the scenebuilder I'm afraid. You could take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/library-panel.htm maybe It will help you.

Comment: If you edit your question to include your FXML file and current controller class I can write you an answer what you could do :)